# Subject at the end of a sentence

Tags: tag-questions

I heard this sentence..."Making pizza **are we**?"

I 'm not sure what structure it is. Does it mean "are we making pizza?"

I don't understand why we can put helping verb and subject at the end of a sentence.

And when should we use the sentence like that?

And should I put a comma (,) like this  "Making pizza **,are we?**"

Could you explain me?

Comment: **Very** much related: [What does “what do we have here” mean?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14237) The two are quite similar. Also, the space always comes **after** the comma, not before; it's: "Making pizza, are we?" not: "Making pizza ,are we?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Making pizza, are we?

is not really a question that needs answering; I'd only expect to hear this uttered if it was quite obvious that someone was indeed making pizza. An equivalent way to express this would be to phrase it as an exclamation rather than a question:

> Oh, look! You're making pizza!

Both of these are ways that a speaker can express how they've just observed something. The question form is sometimes used when someone is caught in the act of doing something they shouldn't be doing:

> Sneaking cookies, are we?

Comment: Many thanks J.R. Your answer, "Oh, look! You're making pizza!" makes me understand the feeling when we say "Making pizza are we?"

Answer (score 3):

This use is a combination of ellipsis and a question tag, usually found in informal spoken English.

From *Practical English Grammar* by Michael Swan,

> **488 question tags (2): advanced points**
>   **8 ellipsis**
>   In sentences with question tags, it is quite common to leave out pronoun subjects and auxiliary verbs. (This is called 'ellipsis'. For details, see 179.)
>   ***(It's a)*** nice day, isn't it?
>   ***(She was)*** talking to my husband, was she?

Your sentence: *"Making pizza, are we?"*
has the same meaning as *"We are making pizza, are we?"*

Also note that non-negative question tags are often used as responses to something that has been said: the speaker repeats what he/she has just heard or learnt, and uses the tag to express interest, surprise, concern or some other reaction.

Since this is a question tag, yes, you should have a comma before the tag.
<sub>Another important note: the common practice is to write the comma immediately after the last word, then a space, and then (those words of) your tag.</sub>

Comment: Many thanks Damkerng T. for your grammar rules, they are useful.